# How to use UIImagePickerController properly on the iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

From the documentation of `UIImagePickerController`:

> On iPad, present the user interface using a popover. Doing so is valid
>   only if the sourceType property of the image picker controller is set
>   to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`.

So what they say is:

- On iPad I MUST use a `UIPopoverController` to display the image picker.
- But at the same time, it is limited to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`

How about the other source types such as `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` or `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`?

In my case I want the user to choose from his photo library and not take a picture with the camera.

Is there a way to use `UIImagePickerController` to pick photos from a library on the iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that documention has a typo in it. I've successfully used `UIImagePickerController` with other `sourceTypes` on iPad - just had to make sure it was in a `UIPopoverController`.